# Contract storing array returning addresses

Tags: contract-development, addresses, arrays, inheritance, import

Below is the contract which imports another contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol"; 

contract StorageFactory {

   
   SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;    
   
   function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
       SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
       simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
   }  
}
```

Now after using function `createSimpleStorageContract()`  and trying to fetch elements of array , we are seeing

[image]

`SimpleStorage` is another contract which I wrote and then imported it. Now `simpleStorageArray` is an array of type `SimpleStorage`. However what I am not able to understand which I try to fetch any value by providing index number in remix , it returns me the address. In every element it should store a new instance of contract why is it storing addresses. Can anyone please explain if array is of SimpleStorage contract type then why it stores & returns address when given index number ?

Answer (score 1):

That’s because when you call new = SimpleStorage() you are creating new smart contract SimpleStorage from StorageFactory and at the same time pushing it’s newly created smart contract address to the simpleStorageArray. After you can check those addresses by index number. Hope that helps.

Comment: How is address getting pushed in the array. `simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage)` it measn that I am pushing the newly created smart contract and not the address. Is there something which I am missing ?

Comment: At the same time You are pushing newly created smart contract and it’s contract address. You can check it by copying  that address and paste it into “ load contract from address “ in Remix.

Comment: That's what I want to know that how address is being pushed into the array given that the type of array is `SimpleStorage`. Like which particular line is making the address go inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you store contract B inside A. It only stores a "reference" to B, that reference is its address. It the only thing it needs to store, the ABI will be used to generate the calls to the contract by the compiler so it won't be stored.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;


contract B {
}

contract A {
    B public b;
    constructor() {
        b = new B();
    }
}
```

When storing an array of contract is exactly the same. Only the addresses are stored.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;


contract B {
}

contract A {
    B[] public bs;
    constructor() {
        bs.push(new B());
    }
}
```